# PHP redirect isn't working for some reason

Tags: php

I'm trying to redirect this PHP page to another page as soon as I get successful update in the database .. but I get a warning from PHP and nothing happens .. Below is the code .. Where did I go wrong ?

```
<html> <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/madscore.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
require('../database/connect.php');
?>
<?php

$id = $_POST["id"]; 
$value = $_POST["score"];
  database_connect();
$query = "update people set Score= Score +".$value." WHERE ID ='".$id."'";
$result = $connection->query($query);

if($result)
  {
?>
<?php
@header("Location: http://www.europe-zone.com/");
exit();
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What warning do you get?

Comment: I not recommended you put `@` at header. If there is error and not shown. It just make you harder to debug it.

Comment: Not related to the problem domain, but you should look at: http://bobby-tables.com/ when you have some time as your code is currently vulnerable.

Answer (score 6):

You should send headers before your HTML page. Put your redirect code just before

```
<html> <head>
```

Regarding to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: Yeah, headers must be sent prior to any output to the browser

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require('../database/connect.php');

$id = $_POST["id"]; 
$value = $_POST["score"];
  database_connect();
$query = "update people set Score= Score +".$value." WHERE ID ='".$id."'";
$result = $connection->query($query);

if($result)
  {
?>
<?php
@header("Location: http://www.europe-zone.com/");
exit();
}

?>
    <html> <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/madscore.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```